# Wowza RTSP clients not showing on /serverinfo

Tags: android, rtsp, rtp, wowza

I have a problem, the clients connected to wowza with **RTSP**(android, blackberry...) are not showing on **:8086/serverinfo** to get the information about IP, flashversion and others.

What I need to do for these clients appears on **:8086/serverinfo** XML?

Answer (score 0):

RTSP player connections to Wowza should be incremented towards RTPSessionCount and RTPConnectionCount in your serverinfo output. You should also see the individual sessions in the RTPSession section. You can test this by playing back rtsp://wowzaIP:1935/vod/sample.mp4 and looking for this URI in your serverinfo output.